# Automatic calling of parent destructor in case of non-virtual destructor?

Tags: c++, destructor

I have a `struct O`, defined in third party code. As it is C code, it does NOT define a `virtual destructor`. (In my case it's the `OVERLAPPED` `struct` from win32 appi).

The customer code that I am modifying has a `class S`, deriving from `class A`, deriving from `struct O`.

```
struct O{};
class A : public O{};
class S : public A{};
```

*None of them* are declaring their destructor as `virtual`.

There would be a leak if one called `delete` on a pointer to an `O`. Sure.

But what does the C++ standard states if I ever call `delete` on a pointer to an S ?
Would it automatically call the destructor of both parent class even though none of them has declared their destructor virtual ? Would it free the relative memory zone of the parents ?

```
S * pS = new S;
delete S; // would this call the parent destructor?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what does the C++ standard states if I ever call delete on a pointer to an S ?

It says the following, from [class.dtor] (§12.4/8 in N4296):

> After executing the body of the destructor and destroying any automatic objects allocated within the body, a
>   destructor for class `X` calls the destructors for `X`’s direct non-variant non-static data members, the destructors
>   for `X`’s direct base classes and, if `X` is the type of the most derived class (12.6.2), its destructor calls the
>   destructors for `X`’s virtual base classes.

So in this case, we call `~S()`, which will then call the destructors for `S`'s direct base classes (`A`), which will then in turn call the destructors for those base classes (`O`).

The `virtual`-ness of the destructor would only matter in the opposite order, namely:

```
O* s = new S;
delete s;
```

In that case, only `~O()` is called - since there are no non-static data members, or direct base classes, or virtual base classes, there's nothing else to do.

Comment: please specify the source of the standards quote. the paragraph numbering is different in different versions of the standard.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf There really needs to be a standard way on SO to quote from the standard. Maybe some new markup that autoimports? That would be cool.

Answer (score 4):

Regarding

```
S * pS = new S;
delete S; // would this call the parent destructor?
```

Yes.
Except that destructor is likely a trivial do-nothing destructor.

Comment: and the memory of the parents should be freed also ?

Comment: @StephaneRolland; yes, everything works OK as long as you have pointer to the most derived object.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, every call of a derived class destructor will lead to destructor calls of all parent classes. But if a class deleted is a pointer to a base class without virtual destructor, no derived class destructor is called (a possible resource leak)

```
struct A {};
struct B : A {};
struct C : B {};

int main() {
    B* p = new C;
    // This will clean up A and B, but leak the resources of C
    delete p;
}
```